# Use QT on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I have a project(C++/dirent.h/OpenCV/Tesseract) on Visual Studio 2013 (Professional with update 2) and I want uses GUI on this project, and I have some questions:

1. I can create the GUI on QT Creator (Drag and Drop) and Bind to my VS2013 Project?
2. qt visual studio add-in have a Drag and Drop?
3. is there any other way to create interfaces with visual studio.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=qt+in+visual+studio&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-beta&channel=sb

Comment: 1 - no. 2 - I believe not. 3- MFC(DLGTEMPLATEEX) or managed .NET, no other way natively from VS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I'm not sure what you mean by "bind", but you can create a `.ui` file in QT Designer which can then be incorporated into your C++ project in Visual Studio. There are multiple ways of doing this - you can load the .ui file dynamically from code using [QUiLoader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/quiloader.html), or you can convert it to C++ code statically using the [UIC tool](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/uic.html) and use the generated code in your project.
2. The QT add-on for Visual Studio automates much of what I described above. You can now have .ui files in your VS project and when you double click them, it will load QT Designer so that you can edit the GUI using the drag/drop tools. When you build your project, it will automatically run the UIC and MOC tools so that your project is built correctly.
3. Yes, as indicated by Marco A.'s comment, you can use MFC to create a native C++ GUI which is Windows based. However that framework is out of date and not really recommended for new projects. You can also use something like Windows Forms to create a GUI in C++/CLI (or other .NET language) and have it call your native C++ code.